# Xamarin.iOS SQLite db not inserting

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, parse-platform

I am trying to populate a sql lite database on iphone. I have a parse object which I am retrieving to my list.

List

```
public class Clinics
   {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Indexed]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string Data1 { get; set; }
        public string Data2{ get; set; }
        public string Data3{ get; set;}
        public string PostCode { get; set; }

        public string Lat {get;set;}
        public string Long {get;set;}

}
```

Then i am using the folloiwing to insert into the db

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        tblResults.Source = new searchResultsTableSource (tableItems);
        tblResults.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;



        // Figure out where the SQLite database will be.
        var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        _pathToDatabase = Path.Combine(documents, "findaphysio.db");


        populateFromParseLocalDB ();

    }
public void populateFromParseLocalDB()
    {
        try
        {
        List<Clinics> _clinics = new List<Clinics> ();


        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("clinics").OrderBy("createdAt").Limit(10);
        query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;

                foreach (var obj in results)
                {
                    var lat = obj.Get<string>("Lat");
                    var lo = obj.Get<string>("Long");
                    var clinicName = obj.Get<string>("Name");
                    _cl.Name = clinicName;
                    _cl.Lat = lat;
                    _cl.Long = lo;
                    _clinics.Add(_cl);
                PopulateSqlLiteDb(clinicName,lat,long);

                 }
            });

            var q = _clinics.Count;

        }
        catch(Exception ex) {

        }


    }
```

Function to save out to sql lite db. I am using Xamrain ios by the way.

```
    public void PopulateSqlLiteDb(string name,string lat,string lng)
    {

        var clinic = new Clinics { Name=name,Lat=lat };
        using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(_pathToDatabase ))
        {
            db.Insert(clinic);
        }

    }
```

Buts its not saving I dont no what the error is as none is thrown.

Comment: PopulateSqlLiteDb(clinicName,lat,long); Is that "long" a typo?  Are you sure your Parse query is returning data?  You are also catching the exception but not doing anything with it - try Console.Writeline(ex.Message) so you can see any exceptions that are caught.

Comment: I'm going to guess you need a `db.Commit` (or similar) to actually save your changes. Just inserting records into a database doesn't usually save them right away.

Comment: @MattBurland this is on the iphone so i cant see if they saved ok or not

Comment: @DavidBuckley: Huh? You said in your question "Buts its not saving". So do you know it saved or not?

Comment: @MattBurland cause i do a count on the db after  to see if the elements are in or not

Comment: You can use Sqlite Manager (a Firefox plugin) to look at the db file created by your app to verify.

Comment: @Jason THIS is a native xmarian.ios monotouch app it launches in simulator not a browser

Comment: The simulator runs on your Mac, and all of it's files are in your filesystem for you to browse.  ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/ - you have to figure out what the GUID of your app is.  The exact path may vary, but you get the idea.